# Is prefacing a class name with underscore the correct way to ensure a class is not usable outside a library?

Tags: dart

If I have a helper class defined in a library that I don't want utilized outside of the library, is the correct hiding mechanism to place an underscore in front of the class name?

```
part of foo;

class Bar { } // made available to users of the foo library

class _BarHelp { } // hidden from users of the foo library
```

Or is there an alternate way of hiding BarHelp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the underscore works for class names the same as functions, methods, and fields, it makes them library-private.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. this is correct way and there is no better way to do this in Google Dart language.
It is also the only possible way to use the privacy (does not provided other levels of privacy).